# How to rename steps and annotation from Cucumber feature file in IntelliJ?

Tags: selenium, intellij-idea, cucumber

I've noticed that when renaming a BDD step on a feature file in IntelliJ, I'm asked to create a brand new method rather than having the previous step and annotation renamed. And renaming the step in the definition method before renaming it on the feature file doesn't rename the annotation. Is there anyway to avoid this please so that I can rename all parts involved on the BDD step at once?

[image]

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this issue by renaming the step in the definition method before renaming it on the feature file.

Comment: Thanks. I'm afraid that doesn't rename the annotation though.